# Javascript multiplier in table - Basic

Tags: javascript, math

I'm new at JavaScript. I want to make a multiplier in Javascript using `prompt()` to get the number n, this is our multiplier, I want to multiply all numbers from 1 to n with the n number.
Example:

if n=4

[image]

and then for bonus eliminate all the same products, so we consider that 2*3 = 3*2, and it should look something like this:

[image]

so, my code so far:

```
// JavaScript Document

function TableOn() { document.write('<table border="1">'); }
function TableOff() { document.write('</table>') }
function TrOn() { document.write('<tr>'); }
function TrOff() { document.write('</tr>'); }
function TdOn() { document.write('<td>'); }
function TdOff() { document.write('</td>'); }
function Izvrsi() {
    var n;
    n = prompt('Insert the multiplayer (n)');
    script0 = TableOn();
    for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        script1 = TrOn();
        /*for(var j=0;j<=n;j++)
            {
                script2 = TdOn();
                document.write(j * n + ' ');
                script6 = TdOff();
            }*/
        script2 = TdOn();
        document.write(i + ' ');
        script3 = TdOff();
        script4 = TrOff();
    }
    for (var j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
        script11 = TrOn();
        script2 = TdOn();
        document.write(j * n + ' ');
        script6 = TdOff();
        script12 = TrOff();
    }
    script5 = TableOff();
}
```

I'm probably not doing something right, can you help me out?

Comment: What are all those `scriptN` variables for? The html-output functions do not return anything. I guess you wanted to nest the two loops, didn't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can call functions without assigning the result to anything. Since you're not doing anything with script0 through script12, you may as well leave them out entirely. Let's fix the indentation while we're at it.

```
function Izvrsi()
{
    var n;
    n=prompt('Insert the multiplayer (n)');
    TableOn();
    for(var i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        TrOn();
        /*for(var j=0;j<=n;j++)
        {
            TdOn();
            document.write(j * n + ' ');
            TdOff();
        }*/
        TdOn();
        document.write(i + ' ');
        TdOff();
        TrOff();
    }
    for(var j=0;j<=n;j++)
    {
        TrOn();
        TdOn();
        document.write(j * n + ' ');
        TdOff();
        TrOff();
    }
    TableOff();
}
```

[image]

Running this, the table is only a single column wide. This makes sense, because you're only writing one `td` inside of each `tr`. If you uncomment that middle section, you'll get the square shape you want.

```
function Izvrsi()
{
    var n;
    n=prompt('Insert the multiplayer (n)');
    TableOn();
    for(var i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        TrOn();
        for(var j=0;j<=n;j++)
        {
            TdOn();
            document.write(j * n + ' ');
            TdOff();
        }
        TdOn();
        document.write(i + ' ');
        TdOff();
        TrOff();
    }
    for(var j=0;j<=n;j++)
    {
        TrOn();
        TdOn();
        document.write(j * n + ' ');
        TdOff();
        TrOff();
    }

    TableOff();
}
```

[image]

The numbers don't look right because you're writing `j * n`, i.e. the index of the current column, times the maximum multiplier. Instead, write `j * i`, i.e. the current column times the current row. While we're at it, let's delete that second `for` block, since it just adds a single column of junk at the end.

```
function Izvrsi()
{
    var n;
    n=prompt('Insert the multiplayer (n)');
    TableOn();
    for(var i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        TrOn();
        for(var j=0;j<=n;j++)
        {
            TdOn();
            document.write(j * i + ' ');
            TdOff();
        }
        TdOn();
        document.write(i + ' ');
        TdOff();
        TrOff();
    }

    TableOff();
}
```

[image]

This looks good, except the table starts from 0 instead of 1, and the row number appears on the right instead of the left. Move the `document.write(i + ' ');` to the front of the for loop, and change your initial i and j values to 1.

```
function Izvrsi()
{
    var n;
    n=prompt('Insert the multiplayer (n)');
    TableOn();
    for(var i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        TrOn();
        TdOn();
        document.write(i + ' ');
        TdOff();
        for(var j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            TdOn();
            document.write(j * i + ' ');
            TdOff();
        }
        TrOff();
    }

    TableOff();
}
```

[image]

You'll need a separate loop to create the column numbers. Fairly simple - just write an empty space and the numbers from 1 to n.

```
function Izvrsi()
{
    var n;
    n=prompt('Insert the multiplayer (n)');
    TableOn();

    //create column numbers
    TrOn();
    TdOn(); document.write(' '); TdOff();
    for(var i=1;i<=n;i++){
        TdOn(); document.write(i + ' '); TdOff();
    }
    TrOff();

    for(var i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        TrOn();
        TdOn();
        document.write(i + ' ');
        TdOff();
        for(var j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            TdOn();
            document.write(j * i + ' ');
            TdOff();
        }
        TrOff();
    }

    TableOff();
}
```

[image]

Lastly, you can eliminate duplicate products by performing a check within the `for(var j...` loop. If i is smaller than j, then don't bother writing anything.

```
function Izvrsi()
{
    var n;
    n=prompt('Insert the multiplayer (n)');
    TableOn();

    //create column numbers
    TrOn();
    TdOn(); document.write(' '); TdOff();
    for(var i=1;i<=n;i++){
        TdOn(); document.write(i + ' '); TdOff();
    }
    TrOff();

    for(var i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        TrOn();
        TdOn();
        document.write(i + ' ');
        TdOff();
        for(var j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            TdOn();
            if (i < j){
                document.write(' ');
            }
            else{
                document.write(j * i + ' ');
            }
            TdOff();
        }
        TrOff();
    }

    TableOff();
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks man, you're awesome, I was so close to it, I'm sorry, I don't know why I had that line commented :s ... I triend to repair the code, but I couldn't create another row... All the numbers were just stuck in the loop, thanks again so much!!!!